# How to use href links in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a Django project like this:

```
-project
    -templates
        file.html
    -project
    -app
        views.py
```

How do I get to call a function in `views.py` from the `file.html` in an `<a href="..."> link </a>`statement?

I already tried `<a href="{% url '..app.views.function' %}">Link</a>`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have an urls.py file ?

Comment: yes one for the project and one for the app

Comment: Url will work with namespace, I think. like : {% url ' myapp : TheNameSpace ' %}
Did you try to includes('path/to/yout/file') the file ?

Comment: yea thank you it fixed it!

Comment: yes already got to fix it with your second comment ;-)thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good practice to give each URL (which in turn maps to a particular view function/class) a `name` parameter when you define the patterns your `urls.py`. Have a [look in the docs here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names)

So,

```
# urls.py
path('detail/', views.detail, name='detail')

# template
<a href="{% url 'detail' %}">Click me to call the detail view.</a>
```

To distinguish view functions between apps [you can namespace them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names).